# Calculate duration of .webm video file in node js

Tags: node.js, webm

I want to calculate the duration of video file in .webm format by using node js code. I have tried following node modules:
1. node-video-lib
2. VideoLength
3. get-video-duration

But I am unable to get duration of video. 
Please guide me to how to implement this in node js code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have test it using `get-video-duration` which works fine for me.

Notice [get-video-duration](https://www.npmjs.com/package/get-video-duration) require `ffprobe`, and [video-length](https://www.npmjs.com/package/video-length) require `mediainfo`.

If you are using linux, you can use `apt` or `yum` to install the respective tools.

Can you be more specific on which os you are using, and what is the error message when you fail to run the library's example?

Comment: Thank you Wan Chap.. video-length worked for me after configuring mediainfo.